Is new React compiler called "Forget" available in any React version?
I'm pretty curious about the new React compiler after watching some videos of it. But as far as I see React team didn't mention anything about it in the React 19 beta blog post. I installed the react@canary version in a new project but I couldn't detect React Forget in it when I checked it through the React Developer tools. When I check Instagram, I can spot that React Forget but I can't spot it in my react@canary app. Is it still not enabled even in the react@canary version? Do you know if there is any version that includes Forget?
Thanks in advance!
